# use sql server .mdf file

Tags: sql, vb.net, project, mdf

I am developing a software with vb.net 2010 and sql server 2008 R2. While developing with my laptop where sql server is running every thing is ok, but when I want to deliver the project to the customer I must install sql server R2 to customer machine. How to get my database .mdf format to use it with my project. Thankyou

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to detach the `mdf` file from your computer and then copy that file to your storage device of your choice say a USB. Afterwards if there is already an installed SQL server in your client you could copy the `mdf` file that you detach and then attach that `mdf` file this time.

To **Detach**:

- **Right Click** on the `Database` that you want to Detach then **Task** -->
  **Detach**

[image]

To **Attach**:

- **Right Click** on the word **Databases** then **Attach**

[image]

Don't forget of course to **Attach** again in your own computer the `Database` that you detached earlier.

Comment: This is fine, but will this deletes the database from the my computer? You said I will need to attach again the database!

Comment: @alrajhi20 No it will not delete your file. You could not copy an mdf file unless it is detach and you could not use it again unless it is attached back.

Comment: Can I use this .mdf database for my softwares? Instead of attaching them again in my sql server? I mean as a local database than server database?

Answer (score 1):

Just make a backup of your database and restore it on the client's machine.

You can do this either with Visual Studio:

- [How to: Back Up a Database (SQL Server Management Studio)](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187510%28v=sql.105%29.aspx)
- [How to: Restore a Database Backup (SQL Server Management Studio)](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177429%28v=sql.105%29.aspx)

...or with T-SQL:

- [How to: Create a Full Database Backup (Transact-SQL)](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191304%28v=sql.105%29.aspx)
- [How to: Restore a Database Backup (Transact-SQL)](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189895%28v=sql.105%29.aspx)

Detaching and attaching the database *(as described in the other answer)* is possible too, but the recommended way is making a backup.
Plus, if you are running at least SQL Server 2008 R2 Standard Edition on your laptop, you can use SQL Server's built-in [backup compression](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb964719%28v=sql.105%29.aspx), which will significantly reduce the size of the backup file *(compared to the regular database size)*.